# Do all Mac OS X 10.6 installations have Perl installed by default?

Tags: perl, macos

For a Mac OS X app where a Perl script (Markdown.pl) will be invoked, I need to know if all Mac OS X 10.6 and later installations have Perl installed be default. Otherwise, we'll have to package it with the app.

Is this confirmed, can I safely assume it?

Comment: I think a more important question is *which* version of Perl Darwin provides.  And the answer is several. Plus I always install my own. So I have all of perl1, perl5.8.9, perl5.10.0, perl5.12.3, perl5.14.0, and perl6 (rakudo) running on my Mac. On other platforms I have even more, and I keep a full perl source tree with all versions ever released in it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

YES.

> Mac OS X already has Perl installed.
>   Open a Terminal application (in the
>   Utilities folder of your Applications
>   folder) and run perl -v to find out
>   which version.
>   http://www.perl.org/get.html

And according to the [**official Snow Leopard specs**](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/specs.html) it comes with **Perl, PHP, Ruby, Rails**.

This [Apple Discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/132895?threadID=132895&tstart=1335) mentions **`Perl (5.8.1)`** as being pre-installed with OS X 10.6.x.
*(this last one's wrong, apparently. See comments of this answer)*

Comment: @WTP: I found the official specs for Snow Leopard listing PERL (no version mentioned though). Updated answer.

Comment: Yes - Perl has been available since 10.0 and before, although the version numbers vary, and generally lag a bit since Apple only updates to a newer Perl version for major 10.x updates. All minor revisions of Mac OS X 10.6 include both 5.10.0 and 5.8.9. (Whoever mentioned 5.8.1 has his cats confused - that shipped with 10.3 "Panther".)

Comment: Incidentally, by "10.0 and before," I'm talking about developer preview releases, not "classic" MacOS. MacPerl was a separate download back in those days. :-)

Comment: Link to Snow Leaopard specs broken.

Answer (score 4):

Given that some packages use perl scripts to uninstall / install, and having never used a Mac that didn't have it; I think it's a fairly safe bet.

Even Perl's website says so: http://www.perl.org/get.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Snow Leopard ships with multiple versions of Perl, I believe.

Comment: Yes, both 5.10.0 and 5.8.9, the latter presumably for compatibility with scripts that don't like 5.10. Apple learned their lesson from the difficult transition from Jaguar to Panther, where they switched from 5.6 to 5.8.1, and broke a *lot* of XS modules in the process.

Answer (score 3):

While its true that Mac's come with Perl, they obviously don't spend a tremendous amount of time thinking about it. The newest XCode [breaks CPAN](http://perlnews.org/2011/04/dealing-with-xcode-4-and-cpan-breakage/). As such you might want to stick with pure Perl modules or the standard distribution until this gets worked out. Even then, those people who do not upgrade will be stuck with a crippled Perl.

More details: http://deflatermouse.livejournal.com/149721.html

Comment: Fortunately, the script the app needs to invoke doesn't need CPAN. :)

Comment: Note that both linked articles advise simply building your own Perl, and avoiding the system Perl. Good advice! After years of trying to write CamelBones to keep up with the system Perl, I'm finally re-writing it from the ground up to include its own.

Comment: @Sherm, there are definitely work-arounds, however one cannot expect that users are willing/going to use them.

Answer (score 2):

This is something a quick Google search would have gotten you the answer to:

http://www.google.com/search?q=mac+os+x+perl+default+install

But yes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ /usr/bin/perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 10 subversion 0) configuration:
  Platform:
    osname=darwin, osvers=10.0, archname=darwin-thread-multi-2level
    uname='darwin neige.apple.com 10.0 darwin kernel version 10.0.0d8: tue may 5 19:29:59 pdt 2009; root:xnu-1437.2~2release_i386 i386 '
    config_args='-ds -e -Dprefix=/usr -Dccflags=-g  -pipe  -Dldflags= -Dman3ext=3pm -Duseithreads -Duseshrplib -Dinc_version_list=none -Dcc=gcc-4.2'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=define, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='gcc-4.2', ccflags ='-arch x86_64 -arch i386 -arch ppc -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/local/include',
    optimize='-Os',
    cppflags='-g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/local/include'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
    ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='gcc-4.2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.6', ldflags ='-arch x86_64 -arch i386 -arch ppc -L/usr/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /usr/lib
    libs=-ldbm -ldl -lm -lutil -lc
    perllibs=-ldl -lm -lutil -lc
    libc=/usr/lib/libc.dylib, so=dylib, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl.dylib
    gnulibc_version=''
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=bundle, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags=' '
    cccdlflags=' ', lddlflags='-arch x86_64 -arch i386 -arch ppc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: MULTIPLICITY PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
                        PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT PERL_MALLOC_WRAP USE_64_BIT_ALL
                        USE_64_BIT_INT USE_ITHREADS USE_LARGE_FILES
                        USE_PERLIO USE_REENTRANT_API
  Locally applied patches:
    /Library/Perl/Updates/<version> comes before system perl directories
    installprivlib and installarchlib points to the Updates directory
  Built under darwin
  Compiled at Jun 24 2009 00:35:27
  @INC:
    /Library/Perl/Updates/5.10.0
    /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0
    /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Library/Perl/5.10.0
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.10.0
    /Network/Library/Perl
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0
```